# Perl multiline Regex for yaml file

Tags: regex, perl, yaml

I'm trying to match subsections of a yaml file. In this example the content of `ab`:

Input:

```
a:
 aa:
  - aaa
 ab:
  - aba
  - abb
 ac:
  - aca
```

Output:

```
aba abb
```

I've tryied s.th. like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -00 -wnl

/a:ab:[ \t]*\n([ \t]+-[ \t]+(\w+)[ \t]*\n)/sg and printf "$2";
```

But this only gives `aba`.

Comment: Why would you do that with a regular expression? Do you want to find something in the yaml, or actually parse it?

Comment: Why are you not just opening the YAML file, like how it was designed to be used? https://perltricks.com/article/29/2013/9/17/How-to-Load-YAML-Config-Files/

Comment: Sure I could do it with yaml processing, but I'm wondering how to do it with a regex ;-)

Comment: It is a bad idea to do it with a regex, for the same reasons it's bad to try and 'do' `XML` with a regex. YAML is a contextual markup language, and regex doesn't do context. Thus you are doomed - at best you'll make some hacky brittle code. Just use a parser. There's quite a few for YAML.

Comment: I switched to the yaml processeing.I thought yaml is regular but since it is a representation of json and now I see json is not regular, so a regex is wrong here.

Comment: Yes. All the reasons you don't want to parse `JSON` with regex apply here too.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to do it with a regex, for the same reasons it's bad to try and 'do' XML with a regex. YAML is a contextual markup language, and regex doesn't do context. Thus you are doomed - at best you'll make some hacky brittle code.

Just use a parser. There's quite a few for YAML.

Like `YAML` for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use YAML;
my $yaml = Load(do { local $/; <DATA> } );

print Dumper \$yaml;

print join "\n", @{$yaml->{a}{ab}},"\n";

__DATA__
a:
 aa:
  - aaa
 ab:
  - aba
  - abb
 ac:
  - aca
```

Answer (score 1):

I take this to be play, curiosity, since you are asking for regex.  For anything serious please use one of the many modules to parse any such (irregular) structure.  Please do not use regex for this.

That said, to answer the direct question

```
perl -0777 -nE '/ab:[^-]+\-\s+(\w+)[^-]+\-\s+(\w+)/gs; say "$1 $2"' data.txt
```

With posted data in `data.txt` file this prints

```
aba abb
```

This is, of course, for your specific data. Once you start tweaking it for more general data sets you'll quickly see why not to use regex.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was only curious how to do it with a regex.

Comment: @jmkg  Yeah, that is how it seemed, which is why I posted this.  For any real work it is really not worth it. It's just endless trouble.